# Hackerrank doesn't accept my code. Why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, while-loop

So the task is to read an integer *N* For all non-negative integers *I < N*, print 
The output format should print *N* lines, one corresponding to each *i*.

For example, the user input is 5 so the output should be...
0
1
4
9
16

Here is my solution.

```
# The first two lines of code were default and already there.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())

# Everything below is my code.
for i in range(0,5):
    while i < 5:
        print(i ** 2)
        i += 1
        break
```

So although this works in Python 3.7, it does not work in Hackerrank because if you were to input an number higher than 5, let's say 7, Hackerrank would output...
0
1
4
9
16
25
36

Python would've just stopped after outputting the number 16.

How can I fix this in Hackerrank?
Here is the link if you want to see the problem yourself.
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/python-loops/problem

Comment: Because you write for i in range(0,5)?

Comment: @user202729 Fair enough on the one question per question. I will remember that in the future. Anyways, hackerrank ran a test when I submitted the code using the input 9. Instead of breaking or stopping the code after passing for a fifth time, it continued 4 more times. In my machine, it would break after 5 times.

Comment: @user202729 print i**2. Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, You should not write in range(0,5) if you want to iterate through n numbers.

Secondly, You do not need to write another while function. You use `for loop` **or** `while loop` for this question.

Change

```
for i in range(0,5):
    while i < 5:
        print(i ** 2)
        i += 1
        break
```

to

```
for i in range(0,n):
    print(i ** 2)
```

Comment: This worked, but if the input n = 9, then shouldn't the range stop at 9 instead of just 5? Why does it do this?

Comment: @Nick Andrulewicz , have a reading. https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop

Answer (score 1):

To add to @Marcus.Aurelianus answer:

If you're in Python 2 change:

```
n = input()
```

Comment: To `raw_input`.

Comment: Never use this in real code. Somebody may enter `__import__('os').system('rm -rf /')` as input.

Answer (score 1):

```
n=int(input())
for i in range(0,n):
    print(i*i)
```

Comment: Also, answers without explanation are rarely useful.

Comment: sorry some typing errors have eccored because i was answering from my mobile.

Comment: user202729 if you have visited the link of hackerrank of the question then you would come to know that thee question is self explanatory.

Comment: **Questions should be self-contained.**

Answer (score 0):

Because there are two wrong things in your answer.

The first one is that you don't write your value for N, you've got to get the user in.

Secondly, the math operation is wrong. You need to fix `print(i ** 2)` as `print(i * 2)` so you can get the result they want. That's probably why it doesn't accept.

My answer to the same question had been as follows.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
n = int(input(""))
i = 0
while i < n:
    r = i * i
    i += 1
    print(r)
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python2:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(raw_input())
for number in range(0, n):
    print(number*number)
```

In Python3:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
for number in range(0, n):
    print(number*number)
```

Answer (score 0):

In python 3:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    for i in range(0,n):
        if i<n:
            print(i*i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple and easy-to-understand solution

```
 if __name__ == '__main__':
        n = int(input())
        if n>-1: # it proceeds only in number in not negative int
            for num in range(0,n): #takes one digit at a time from 0 to n
                print(num**2)
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```py
if __ name __ == ' __main __':
     n = int(input())

for i in range(n):
    while i < 10:
        print(i ** 2)
        i += 1
        break
```

Answer (score -2):

```
 if __name__ == '__main__':
     n = int(input())

for i in range(0,n):
    (i*i) and 1 <=n <=20
    print(i*i)
```

> 

Comment: This does not work. You try to read `n` if main but then reference it outside of that if block. Then your for loop contains a no-effect statement at the beginning.